# A gentle reference for flat modules with exercises

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

I would like to learn about sources that give a gentle introduction to flat modules, with exercises. Could you recommend me some source? This might be a section in a book, or some article.

I am reading the *Primer in Commutative Algebra* of James Milne, and I find the section on flatness harder than average in this (great) text. So I would like to find some other pedagogical source that would contain a bit more details and examples.

Answer (score 2):

I like [Osborne's Basic Homological Algebra](http://books.google.ch/books/about/Basic_Homological_Algebra.html?id=Zdk7w3Jl64oC&redir_esc=y) very much. Check chapter 2 for a gentle introduction to proj. / inj. & flat modules. You can find some exercises at the end of it (check in particular ex. 11, aka the "flat test lemma").

Comment: Thank you for this recommendation, I will have a look

Comment: You are welcome. Also the remaining chapters are quite well written.